# send data from 2 bluetooth to android device

Tags: java, eclipse, bluetooth

I need to send simple data-an integer- from two bluetooth devices to an android device. I know that the Bluetooth Chat is the base upon it, but it refers to connection of only one bluetooth device. Does anyne has managed to change it or has any hint to give me??
Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean saying "from two bluetooth devices to an android device" ?